# Using Notepad++ Regex expressions to replace date format 2007-10-26T06:36:28 with the standard YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I'm trying to edit an XML file with hundreds of dates. I want to replace all odd formats like

```
2007-10-26T06:36:28
2008-08-28+00:00
```

with a `yyyy-MM-dd` format date like `2020-02-13`.

I'm using Notepad++ Regex for this. So far I've found:

```
find:
([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+) 

replace with:
\1-\2-\3
```

however I want to adapt this expression to look for the previously mentioned formats.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question and post a representative of the entries in their original xml format?

Comment: Are the dates in your notepad file separated by spaces or anything of the kind?

Comment: This works for your test cases, but if you have more wacky formats then you'll need to provide more information: `(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})(?:T|\+)(?:\d{2}:?+)+` replaced with `$1`

Comment: Replacing `([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)` with `\1-\2-\3` is a null operation, that is doing nothing!

Answer (score -1):

The answer was more simple than I thought. I used find ([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+) replace with \1-\2-\3 in order to make sure my date formats were correct, then for any special formats like 2008-08-28+00:00 I just used find +00:00 replace with 'nothing', just a simple find/replace expression.